# Truncate Width of <p> to width of inner text which is rigth-aligned

Tags: html, css, right-align

I am right-aligning text inside of a fixed width `<p>`. I would like the width of the `<p>` to then truncate so that it becomes the minimum width possible which respects that wrapping,  Basically, the width of the actual text.

check out this fiddle: I want the heading to be horizontally aligned with the word "Example".

EDIT: To be more clear: I want the `<p>` to be right-aligned. I also want to horizontally align a heading with the left edge of said right-aligned `<p>`.

https://jsfiddle.net/1ojkp4ys/30/

I would like the solution to work with any text so not just hard coding some padding

```
<div>
  <h4>
    PLEASE LINE ME UP
  </h4>
  <p>
    This is some example
  </p>
</div>
```

```
p {
  width: 50px;
  text-align: right;
}

div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Notice how the "P" in "Please" in the heading is left of the "e" in "example"

Comment: Copy the code you have in https://jsfiddle.net/1ojkp4ys/30/ and paste here as a [mcve].

Comment: why not just give the width for the heading ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having a fixed width for the paragraph, use `<br/>` to multi-line it. The width of the paragraph will then be precise to the edges of its text and horizontal alignment with another element will be easy.

Answer (score -1):

Removed the width from `p` and removed the `align`.

Based on what you said, it sounds like you want the heading to be centered, so use `h1{text-align : center ;}`.

This is way better from a designer's perspective. But if you are trying to do something else, explain more.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'm trying to have the heading align with the left most point in right-aligned text, so not centered. I want a fixed width because i want my paragraph to be multi-line.